# How to read outlook express contacts from asp.net application?

Tags: asp.net

I want to import contacts from my outlook account to my web application in asp.net, any help?

Answer (score 1):

I was going to say that OE uses the Windows Address Book but that seems to have changed since vista. 
Either way there are [APIs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms629440%28VS.85%29.aspx) that will let you read the data.